# How to check a mongoose object ref if it contains a field that matches?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am not sure if this is done correctly or efficient for that matter... I need to see if a user is found within another users followers/following...

Here is the code:

```
var User = new Schema({

firstName: {type: String},
lastName: {type: String},
following: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]

 ......});



var userId2 = someoneElse;


var userId = req.query.userId;
        User.findOne(userId, function(err, results) {
                if(err) {
                        throw err;

                } else {
                        var i, newArrayF1, newArrayF2, biggerArraySize;
                        newArrayF1 = results.completedChallenges;
                        newArrayF2 = results.joinedChallenges;

                        if(newArrayF2.length > newArrayF1.length) {
                                biggerArraySize = newArrayF2.length;
                        } else {
                                biggerArraySize = newArrayF1.length;
                        }
                        for(i =0, i < biggerArraySize, i++) {
                                if(newArrayF1[i].followers.indexOf(userId2)) {
                                        var obj = {mtype: 2};
                                res.json(obj);
                                }

                                if(newArrayF2[i].following.indexOf(userId2)) {
                                        var obj = {mtype: 1};
                                res.json(obj);
                                }

                        }

                        if(i == biggerArraySize) {
                                var obj = {mtype: 0};
                                res.json(obj);
                        }

                }

        });
```

I am running a check to see if a user has a following/follower connection with the other user and returning an integer that associates with it,

Comment: If it's present in both followers and following, then what should mtype be?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use `populate` when fetching the user.

```
User.findOne(userId).populate('following').exec(function (err, user) {
     user.following.forEach(function (person) {
           // here you have access to each person in the array
     }
}
```

Comment: ok and the other if statement searchs and what not are sufficient then?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish there

Comment: I am running a check to see if a user has a following/follower connection with the other user and returning an integer that associates with it, also, if I do it this way, then I have to do a second query with .populate('followers')... so does this make more sense than my way